# Language pack can not be installed on 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation, language

I installed Windows 2008 server R2 standard from the CD (english), applied updates and now I need to Install the Dutch language interface. It is provided on the DVD, but refuses to install, telling me it is incompatibel with this version of Windows.

Where can I get the right version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Microsoft. IIRC langauge packs are enterprise only, so basically you download them from the MS licensing site.

Comment: thank you, After diggin into the ms site, I found out the files can also be downloaded from : http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=nl&FamilyID=3a7fb7a2-3519-495b-9bc5-2007082ca9a6#filelist